# In C++ how to copy variables without coping read/write access

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a variable (A) with a write access lock. I want to copy this variable to another variable (B) but I don't wont to copy the write access lock.  How can I do this?

```
    WICRect rcLock = { 0, 0, sc_bitmapWidth , sc_bitmapHeight };
    IWICBitmapLock *pILock=NULL;
    hr =pWICBitmap->Lock(&rcLock, WICBitmapLockWrite, &pILock); //this is where I create the lock 


    hr=pRT->CreateSharedBitmap(
        IID_IWICBitmapLock,
        static_cast<void *>(pILock),
        &bp2,
        &m_pBitmap1
        ); 

//m_pBitmap1 is locked its a ID2D1Bitmap object

    m_pBitmap2=m_pBitmap1; //i want  m_pBitmap2 to be unlocked
```

Comment: You should add more details to your question, especially what exactly that "write access lock" is. Posting a minimal piece of code with A's type and the operation you're trying to accomplish would help too.

Comment: okay, I made the changes you requested.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't.

Since you cannot guarantee that reading the entire storage will happen without interruption from some other thread, you **must** aquire the *write* lock to make sure that noone is writing to your storage, while you are trying to read from it.

If thread (1) starts reading, and thread (2) jumps in and start writing it's a possibility that what thread (1) actually retrieves is a middle-ground before the *previous* and *newly* stored value representation.

The middle-ground sure isn't wanted, and it's probably not even a valid value; ie. it's bad.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the write lock? Basically What I want is to  create a new memory location and copy the values of the locked memory location to it and assign it to a new value. It may not be a valid value but I want to give it a try. How can I do it?

Comment: @user3715097 you could try removing it, there's nothing stopping you; just keep in mind that you will probably run into data-races/synchronization issues.

Comment: m_pBitmap1->Release(); doesn't seem to work. How can I remove it?

Comment: @user3715097 oh, you mean programmtically. do `pWICBitmap->Release()`, I'll write it as an answer on your other question if I understood you correctly, please let me know.

Comment: hr=pWICBitmap->Release(); returns the system cannot find the file specified.